# Navigation drawer и ImageView(PhotoView)

Tags: android, android-navigation-drawer

Доброго времени суток, имеется проблема, сделал ImageView с функцией загрузки фотографий из библиотеки и последующего их масштабирования, все работало замечательно, до момента добавления NavigationDrawer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black"
    tools:context="com.example.master.yobcolob.MainActivity">

    <com.github.chrisbanes.photoview.PhotoView
        android:id="@+id/photo_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription=""
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp">


        <com.mxn.soul.flowingdrawer_core.FlowingDrawer
            android:id="@+id/drawerlayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clipChildren="false"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:edMenuBackground="#2aededed"
            app:edMenuSize="260dp"
            app:edPosition="1">

            <!--content-->
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <!--menu-->
            <com.mxn.soul.flowingdrawer_core.FlowingMenuLayout
                android:id="@+id/menulayout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/id_container_menu"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            </com.mxn.soul.flowingdrawer_core.FlowingMenuLayout>

        </com.mxn.soul.flowingdrawer_core.FlowingDrawer>

    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

---

```
package com.example.master.yobcolob;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.github.chrisbanes.photoview.PhotoView;
import com.mxn.soul.flowingdrawer_core.ElasticDrawer;
import com.mxn.soul.flowingdrawer_core.FlowingDrawer;

public class MainActivity  extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener {

    //Объявляем используемые переменные:
    private ImageView imageView;
    private final int Pick_image = 1;
    private FlowingDrawer mDrawer;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Вызываем  дорогой Метод открытия галереи:
        onClick();
        //Связываемся с нашим ImageView:
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        // Шторка
        mDrawer = (FlowingDrawer) findViewById(R.id.drawerlayout);
        mDrawer.setTouchMode(ElasticDrawer.TOUCH_MODE_BEZEL);

    }

/* //Вызываем меню
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_cat1) {
            onClick();
            return true;
        }

        if (id == R.id.action_cat2) {

            return true;
        }
        if (id == R.id.action_cat3) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    */
    public void onClick() {
                //Вызываем стандартную галерею для выбора изображения с помощью Intent.ACTION_PICK:
                Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                //Тип получаемых объектов - image:
                photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
                //Запускаем переход с ожиданием обратного результата в виде информации об изображении:
                startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, Pick_image);
            }
    //Обрабатываем результат выбора в галерее:
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);
        switch(requestCode) {
            case Pick_image:
                if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                    try {
                        //Получаем URI изображения, преобразуем его в Bitmap
                        //объект и отображаем в элементе ImageView нашего интерфейса:
                        final Uri imageUri = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                        final InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                        Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                        //Добавляем бибилиотеку определяем наш фотвью,и передаем битмап в Фотовьюшку
                        PhotoView photoView = (PhotoView) findViewById(R.id.photo_view);
                        photoView.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
        }}
        @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Насколько я понял конфликт в XML главного активити

Comment: https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView